# How to get Logo instead of ERC20 TOKEN on transfer page?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, etherscan

How to change this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

on etherscan token detail page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its very simple follow steps as I mentioned below.

1. Verify your source code, then follow next steps.
2. Click below link https://etherscan.io/contactus
3. Select  dropdown **Update token information**
4. Fill details and submit form.

Comment: @Sowmay Jain Can you please accept the ans, that will help community