# ERC token not showing up in Etherscan.io search. Duplicate names exist

Tags: contract-development, transactions, blockchain, tokens, contract-deployment

I created a token called LUV. There are other tokens with this name and they all show up in a search on etherscan.io but mine doesn't. The contract address is  0xaa0Cf928DBd96C8109c54f8809A0317581bC8BAe
I also sent 1000 of the tokens to another address and it didn't make a difference. It still doesn't show up in a search. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clear instructions. I will get to work on that.

Comment: @Giovani can you please click tick mark. That will help community to find answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your's contract is not showing because, token is not verified by  etherscan.io. Other LUV token is filled coming on global search because that coin has basic information like link, logo, social links etc. For that you need to contact etherscan.io team. Once they will verify it automatically show your token in main search.

Currently your token is coming to list follow below steps:

1. https://etherscan.io
2. Click token > view token
3. Search for LUV (Not global search)
4. You will find your coin address also showing, along with other coins address's
5. If you observe you will find one coin address is verified already, with that name.

[image: For more details plz find an attachment]

[How to get Logo instead of ERC20 TOKEN on transfer page?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38575/how-to-get-logo-instead-of-erc20-token-on-transfer-page/38578#38578)