# How to attach a Logo to an ERC20 Token

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20

I have created an ERC20 Token with MEW. However, when I send it to people who have different ERC20 wallets, the logo of my token is always *Ethereum like* How do I put my own logo on the token so that people see that and not the ethereum logo? I have seen quite a few people who have created ERC20 tokens for fun, having their own logo show on the token and I do not know how they do that!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38575/how-to-get-logo-instead-of-erc20-token-on-transfer-page

Comment: This question is about whatever dapp (or perhaps several dapps) you want to render your logo. It has nothing to do with go or erc20.